# storing data in factory on asynchronus call in angular

Tags: angularjs, http, variables, save, factory

I have the following Problem. I am getting Data from the API and display it to the user. It is a list with images, that you can scroll through. When the User clicks on the Image, he will get more Information about the image on a different site.

I want to store the Data that i got from the server in a local variable inside of the factory. But somehow the Data is not saved properly and this is driving me nuts.

```
.factory('PostService', function($q, $http, domain){
var posts = [];

return {
    getInit: function(){
        var self = this;
        //get fresh elements
        console.log("get fresh elements");
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: domain+'/api/v1/statuses'
        }
        return $http(req).then(function(success){
            self.storeLocal(success.data.data); //store data in factory
            return success.data.data; //return data to controller
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

After the call, i have a second function that should access the posts and get more elements from the server.

```
getAfter: function(){
        var self = this;
        console.log("get more elements");
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: domain+'/api/v1/statuses',
        data: {
            'last_status': posts[posts.length - 1].id
        }
        }
        return $http(req).then(function(success){
            if(success.data.data.length > 0){
                self.storeLocal(success.data.data);
                return success.data.data;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    storeLocal: function(posts){
        posts = posts.concat(posts);
    },
```

But it tells me that posts is undefined. So whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So i could fix this problem, by replacing the storeLocal function with just `posts = posts.concat(success.data.data)` and it works.

But isnt there a way, to use the structure i just presented? I want to this to work, because later i can just switch how the storing is working.